# DataAdapter overloaded method error

Tags: c#

Below I mention my dropdonlist code.  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(str2) field showing some invalid overloaded method and I am using separate class for connection.Anybody help me to solve the error
conn=sqlconnection(separate class).
query=function for "select" method.

```
protected void fill2()
{             
           string str1 = "select CompanyID from Company where CompanyName='" + ddcompany.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
           SqlDataReader dr2 = conn.query(str1);
           if (dr2.Read())
           {
               string id1 = dr2[0].ToString();

               string str = "select ZoneID  from Zone where Zone='" + ddzone.SelectedItem.Text + "' and CompanyID='" + id1 + "'";
               SqlDataReader dr1 = conn.query(str);
               if (dr1.Read())
               {
                   string id = dr1[0].ToString();
                   string str2 = "select Region from Region where ZoneID='" + id + "'";
                   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(str2);
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   sda.Fill(dt);
                   ddregion.DataSource = dt;
                   ddregion.DataBind();


               }
```

Comment: what is: conn.query(str1);? conn = SqlConnection ?? this hase no method named query...

Comment: @ Edi G.Conn=sqlconnection.It is separate class for connection and query is class for selection

Answer (score 0):

There is no constuctor in SQLDataAdapter with para SqlDataAdapter(string query)

Change this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(str2);
```

to this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(str2, conn);
```

[More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

by the way. Your code is not realy best practice.. [Basic example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)

Comment: G.yes I checked the example it is just select all employees from table but in my case I have to find CompanyID,Zone ID and region.

Comment: is your conn object an SqlConnection-object?

Comment: @ Edi G. yes it is my connection object

Comment: jap.. this is the problem.. it is YOUR connection object. SqlDataReader expected an SqlConnection object (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)